# Design Mode button is disabled in QNX Momentics IDE

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm trying to learn BlackBerry 10. 
When I create new cascades project, it opens by default main.qml file.
And the default mode is **source mode**.

In the editor Design Mode, Vertical Split Mode and other buttons are not highlighted.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1°) Open: Window > Preferences > Blackberry > QML Editor
And uncheck disable QML preview

2°) Update your Graphic card driver

Answer (score 0):

The QML Preview for the current SDK version 10.1 is disabled for non-Windows systems by default ([QML Preview Considerations](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/releasenotes/#limitations)). However, [it's in place since 10.2](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/releasenotes_beta_10_2/#new) which is in deep Beta at the moment.